# Valid range for QDateTime::fromMSecsSinceEpoch

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I discovered a strange behavior in `QDateTime` of Qt 4.8 regarding `fromMSecsSinceEpoch`. The following code does not produce the result I would expect:

```
assert(
    QDateTime::fromMSecsSinceEpoch(
        std::numeric_limits<qint64>::max()
    ).isValid() == true
);
assert(
    QDateTime::fromMSecsSinceEpoch(
        std::numeric_limits<qint64>::max()
    ).toMSecsSinceEpoch() == std::numeric_limits<qint64>::max()
);
```

While the first assertion is true, the second fails. The returned result from Qt is `-210866773624193`.
The [doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdatetime.html#fromMSecsSinceEpoch) for `QDateTime::fromMSecsSinceEpoch(qint64 msecs)` clearly states:

> There are possible values for msecs that lie outside the valid range of QDateTime, both negative and positive. The behavior of this function is undefined for those values.

However, there is no any explicit statement about the valid range.

I found this [Qt bug report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-52284) about an issue regarding timezones in Qt  5.5.1, 5.6.0 and 5.7.0 Beta.
I am not sure wheter this is a similar bug, or if the value I provided to `QDateTime::fromMSecsSinceEpoch(qint64 msecs)` is simply invalid.

What is (or rather should be) the maximum value that can be passed to this function and yields correct behavior?

Comment: _The range of valid dates is from January 2nd, 4713 BCE, to sometime in the year 11 million CE_

Comment: I read that, but it doesnt give an exact value

Comment: The documentation doesn't give an exact value, it's somewhere near `11'000'000 * 365 * 3600 * 1000`

Comment: @Danh isn't it `11'000'000 * 365 * 24 * 3600 * 1000`?

Comment: @wasthishelpful yes, forgot that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::numeric_limits<qint64>::max() ms` yields `9 223 372 036 854 775 807 ms`, or `9 223 372 036 854 775 s`, or `2 562 047 788 015 hours`, or `106 751 991 167 days`, or `292 471 208 years`: that's far beyond the year 11 million in the valid range of `QDateTime`.

From [the doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdatetime.html#range-of-valid-dates), valid dates start from January 2nd, 4713 BCE, and go until `QDate::toJulianDay()` overflow: `2^31 days` (max value for signed  integer) yields nearly `5 000 000 years`. That's `185 542 587 187 200 000 ms` (from January 2nd, 4713 BCE, not from Epoch), "little" more than `2^57`.

**EDIT:**

After discussion in the comments, you checked Qt4.8 sources and found that `fromMSecsSinceEpoch()` uses `QDate(1970, 1, 1).addDays(ddays)` internally, where the number of days is calculated directly from the `msecs` parameter.

Since `ddays` is of type `int` here, this would overflow for values larger than `2^31`.

Comment: I did a binary search and it looks like the largest valid value to pass to `fromMSecsSinceEpoch()` is `185542587187199999` which yields _Fr. Jul 11 23:59:59 5881580_ in UTC and is far away from 11 million CE.

Comment: Ok, that back ups my binary search result. However, it is still not a date _sometime in the year 11 million CE_ as the doc states. Is it a problem with the doc, then?

Comment: Looks like it is. The doc has change in Qt5 (see [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#range-of-valid-dates)), so I can't look in the Qt5 code I have to find a complete answer. You will have to take a look in your sources of Qt4.8 if you want/need to go further (feel free to share the result here so I can update my answer ;) )

Comment: I should have done this earlier...`fromMSecsSinceEpoch()` uses `QDate(1970, 1, 1).addDays(ddays)` internally where the number of days is calculated directly from the `msecs` parameter. Since `ddays` is of type `int` here this would overflow for values larger than 2^31. So your calculation is correct and I would call this a bug in Qt 4.8